# Почему у fullscreen блока присутствуют данные отступы?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему-то слева и сверху присутствуют отступы. Хотелось бы убрать.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.block1 {
  background: green;
}

.block2 {
  background: black;
}

.block3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NIKIS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block block1"></div>
    <div class="block block2"></div>
    <div class="block block3"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

потому что у `body` есть стандартные отступы - уберите их через css и будет вам счастье

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.block1 {
  background: green;
}

.block2 {
  background: black;
}

.block3 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>NIKIS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="block block1"></div>
    <div class="block block2"></div>
    <div class="block block3"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```